# Difficulties with re-writing code following conventions

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, pep8

I'm currently working in my free time collaborating with a friend on their project which is a flappy bird like game. The first task was to rewrite the code in order to make it more scalable and easy to read. I've done some progress but I can't get the moving parts of the game work.

After some research of how to organize the code I've stumbled on in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application) and it worked for most of the project, an example of how I've structured my code:

The `game.py` on the root project runs the game normally just by executing it. The rewritten code is composed of  the `app.py`, the `entities` and `screens` folder.

Structure:

```
    .
    |-- app.py
    |-- entities
    |   |-- lean.py
    |   `-- trapper.py
    |-- game.py
    |-- lean.py
    |-- requirements.txt
    |-- screens
    |   `-- game.py
    `-- trapper.py
```

app.py:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from screens import Game_screen

class Main_application(tk.Frame):
    '''Creates the application frame

    Args:
        parent: The root of the application.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, *kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        # <TODO: The rest of the application >
        self.game_screen = Game_screen(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main_application(root).pack(
        side = 'top',
        fill = 'both',
        expand = True
    )
    root.mainloop()
```

screens/game.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from entities import Lean
from entities import Trapper

gravity = 10
height = 600
width = 400
speed = 35 # (0 == faster | 0 > slower)

class Game_screen(tk.Frame):
    '''Generates the Game Screen.

    Args:
        master: The application frame.
    '''
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # Background creation
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            master, 
            width = width, 
            height = height, 
            bg ='cyan'
        )
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Player instance
        self.trapper = Trapper(
            width, 
            height, 
            10, 
            10, 
            gravity
        )

        # Obstacle instance
        self.lean = Lean(
            height, 
            30, 
            150, 
            height
        )
        self.init = 0
        self.speed = speed
        self.score = 0

        # Player creation
        self.trapper_obj = self.canvas.create_oval(
            self.trapper.x - self.trapper.size,
            self.trapper.y - self.trapper.size,
            self.trapper.x + self.trapper.size,
            self.trapper.y + self.trapper.size, 
            fill="yellow", 
            tags="trapper"
        )
        master.bind('<Up>', self.comandoUp)

        # Obstacle creation
        self.lean_obj_top = self.canvas.create_polygon(
            self.lean.get_lean_top(),
            fill='purple',
            tags='lean_top'
        )

        # Obstacle creation
        self.lean_obj_bot = self.canvas.create_polygon(
            self.lean.get_lean_bot(),
            fill='purple',
            tags='lean_bot'
        )

        # Score
        self.canvas.create_text(
            (width-60, 20),  
            text='score: {}'.format(
                self.score
            )
        )

        # Start game
        if(self.init == 1): 
            self.trapper.moveUp()
            self.trapper.moveDown()
            self.lean.move(self.trapper.vHor)

        # Side-scroller
        if(self.lean.x < -self.lean.l):
            self.lean = Lean(height, 30, 150, width)

        # Collision
        pos_t = self.canvas.bbox(self.trapper_obj)
        collision = self.canvas.find_overlapping(
            pos_t[0],
            pos_t[1],
            pos_t[2],
            pos_t[3]
        )

        for x in collision:
            tagx = self.canvas.gettags(x)[0]
            if tagx == 'lean_top' or tagx == 'lean_bot':
                print("Hit the pipe")
                quit()
            elif tagx == 'mid':
                self.score += self.lean.score
                if self.lean.score == 1:
                    print(self.score)
                self.lean.score = 0

            if self.trapper.y > height:
                print("Fell off")
                quit()


        # Render and moves scenario
        self.canvas.after(self.speed)
        master.update_idletasks()
        master.update()

    def comandoUp(self, event):
        self.trapper.up = 6
        self.init = 1
```

Most of the elements are displayed on the screen, but they are static and I couldn't find a solution during the whole weekend. If the information provided isn't enough I provide a link to my [repository](https://github.com/paulo-henrique-ph/trapper_bird) for better understanding.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I have coded myself a [Flappybird](https://github.com/DamienAllonsius/flappy_bird) also, using pygame.

Comment: did you run it in termina/console/cmd.exe to check if you get error message ?

Comment: in `__init__` you should only init variables, not check collision and not run it again with `after()` . You should have separated function which you run with `after()` and it should move object and check collisions.

Comment: No error is shown, maybe the key is not biding or the logic isn't reaching the movement methods but i don't know for sure, if i find somenthing that helps i will update this post

Comment: @furas i will try that and give you updates

Comment: you can put some `print()` in functions to see if they work. Normally  I use `root.after(10, function_name)` at the end of `def function_name():` to run it every 10ms. And I have to run it normally in `__init__` - `function_name()` - to start this loop.

Comment: I have updates about the issue, actuallly the game screen is embeded in the  main application so the key bind couldn't be reached, now i have to figure out how i can estabilish  a communication with the main application and the entities inside the embeded screen, i apologize for the poorly written code and these beginner mistaskes but it's my first time with python GUI